# Google Maps javascript API icon z-index not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps javascript API as follows

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                var mapOptions = {
                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                    zoom: 6,
  scaleControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
    },

                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.444879, 24.743874), 

                    // How you would like to style the map. 
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                    styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#d3d3d3"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"color":"#808080"},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b3b3b3"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"weight":1.8}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#d7d7d7"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ebebeb"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#a7a7a7"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#efefef"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#696969"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#737373"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#d6d6d6"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#dadada"}]}]
                };

                // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://media.voog.com/0000/0036/9367/photos/naftalogo_facebook.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(62,62)); // Create a variable for our marker image.
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.444879, 24.743874),
                        icon:image, //use our image as the marker
                    map: map,
                    optimized: false,
                    zIndex: 100
                });
                marker.set('zIndex', google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 999);
            }
        </script>
     <div id='map'></div>
```

And on top of the map there is a div with a line in the center with z-index:99 as follows:

```
    .contact-wrap:after {
        content: '';
        width: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 99;
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        top: 0;
    }
.contact-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1370px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Although I have set the z-index for the map icon properly in my opinion, the line is still on top of the icon.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Try to set the icon's position css rule to `relative` in your css, this should make the `z-index` apply correctly to your icon.

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: How do I address the icon with a css rule?

Comment: One way would be to target the unique image name by source: img[src^='http://pathtoyourimage'], otherwise inspect your html and try to target your icon by using the google map as the parent selector e.g. #map div > img. You could also set a title on your image and use a css selector to target the img with the title.

Comment: Jako Basson, I have the same problem so I tried your suggestion. my map div is "map" so I put in the CSS
#map img{position:relative}
but that does nothing. So I tried visibility:hidden but then the whole map disappears. I would have tried setting a title on the image, but I can't see how to do that. Can you help with any further guidance?

Comment: Instead of targeting the #map img{position:relative}, try to target the image with the src attr #map img[src^='pathtoyourimage'] {position:relative!important;} . Try using the !important to force your style to override any styles that might be applied to the image.

Comment: Also if you want to target it by title try adding a title when creating your marker object : var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: 'your title'
    });

Comment: I've tried both your solutions and neither seem to work, apparently because the CSS is not picking up the attributes in square brackets. I put a title on the markers and cut the line of CSS down to 
img[title] {visibility:hidden}. 
They are still visible. If I reduce it further to 
img {visibility:hidden} 
everything is hidden including the map, which at least shows that the CSS file in general is working.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the solution turned out to be somewhere else entirely. I was creating and writing the z-index as a string, not a number. But, thank you Jako, for your patient assistance.